# AVPlayer stops on background

Tags: ios, avplayer, swift2

I am using AVPlayer to play audio from an URL. Everything works as expected until the APP goes on background or the iphone enter in sleep mode.

How can I prevent this from happening.

I've added to the info.plist:

[image]

Here is my code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let playTrackID = tracks[indexPath.row].trackID

    let urlString = url
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL:url)

    avPlayer.play()

}
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE: SOLVED** by @Danil Gontovnik

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let playTrackID = tracks[indexPath.row].trackID

    let urlString = url
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    do {

        avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL:url)

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

    }

    catch {

        print("Something bad happened. Try catching specific errors to narrow things down")
    }


    avPlayer.play()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you forgot to set your AVAudioSession to be active. Try to add this code:

```
var categoryError: NSError?
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &categoryError)

if categoryError != nil {
    // Handle error
}

var activeError: NSError?;
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: &activeError)

if activeError != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

More information on **AVAudioSession** can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/).

Comment: I tried that but i get an error: "Extra argument error in cal"

Comment: Which line exactly you get that?

Comment: I am using Swift2 so I have to add  do/try/catch implementation. It works thank you very much.

Comment: It's still stops playing when I exit the app.. Any idea?

Comment: You specified category AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, try to use **AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback**.

Comment: Sorry my bad.. It works now. The only thing that makes the music stop is if I go back to the main view controller any idea why?

Comment: Maybe because your player becomes nil?

Comment: Thats odd because I have a segue that goes to another controller and the music keeps playing. But if I click the back button on the navigation it stops.

Comment: When you go to another view controller with a segue, you previous view controller is in memory. Once you go back - your view controller and related objects are deallocated. If you want to have a player which plays from any screen, I would recommend to use **singleton** pattern. Here is an [example](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/).

Comment: Do you have any example in Swift2?

Comment: This [article](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/design-patterns-singletons--cms-23886) includes info about singleton in swift (probably 1.0 or 1.2, but should not be a big difference).